# Cropping the Mediabox does not work for some pdfs

Tags: python, pypdf

I wrote a little script which shall blank out the lower half of a PDF document. The document itself shall remain the same size, but the lower half shall be just white.
(This is to remove the "instructions" part from parcel labels of German parcel comanies like DHL and Hermes.)

To do this, I take the PDF page, adjust the Mediabox, and then merge this page onto a new, blank page.

Fortunately, this works as intended with the PDFs I need it for. However, I also tried a few other PDFs and for some, it just does not work. It copies over the complete PDF. This happens for example, when my code is given this file: https://www.veeam.com/veeam_backup_product_overview_ds.pdf

Here is the code:

```py
import pypdf   # PyPDF2, 3 and 4 are deprecated. PyPDF is currently in active development

reader = pypdf.PdfReader(source_filename)
writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

# get first page
page = reader.pages[0]  
# create new page
new_page = pypdf.PageObject.create_blank_page( None, width = page.mediabox.width, height = page.mediabox.height ) 
# crop original
page.mediabox.bottom = ( page.mediabox.top - page.mediabox.bottom ) / 2 + page.mediabox.bottom 
# merge original into empty new page
new_page.merge_page( page )

writer.add_page(new_page)
with open(output_file, "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

Can anyone explain why it does not work sometimes?

Comment: Can you supply the output PDF as well as the input?

Comment: @johnwhitington The input PDF is linked above. I'm not sure if I run into copyright issues if I provide the output here. But you can generate it yourself using the above script.

Comment: Thank you @K-J for the explanation. All boxes in the PDF linked above (artbox, bleedbox, cropbox, mediabox and trimbox) are the same (`[0, 0, 595.276, 841.89]`). Also, I don't want to remove invisible objects from the PDF data. I guess that can be very hard as you would have to determine the visibility. I am just curious why it works sometimes and sometimes not. I also tried playing with the cropbox instead of the mediabox, but it had no effect.